# numpy and scanf equivalents, turning binary output stream into an array

Tags: numpy, gpib

I am using linux-gpib library to talk to bench equipment. I can ask the device for output
from it's buffer, and it streams to std out. I use something like:

```
import gpib 

gpib.write(16,"FORM3;OUTPDATA;") #FORM3 is binary

data=gpib.read(16,10000)
```

I'm not sure what the output format looks like, I forgot how the data is delimited.
But I figure I need to do some kind of scanf function to grab the floats and out them into 
an array.

I installed numpy, and think there should be a way to ask python to grab the floats from the stream and put them into an array.

Google hasn't helped much, numpy is really new to me. I know the MATLAB and C command OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the data to a string, as you did above, use `numpy.fromstring`:

```
data = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8'
print np.fromstring(data, sep=' ')
# [ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.]
```

Typically in Python, more general parsing is done with regular expressions rather than scanf. See [sscanf in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175080/sscanf-in-python)

Comment: thank you, I'll try this solution. If the delimiter happens to be newline \n or comma , how would I implement that ?

Comment: I think I figured out previous comment question;http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html