# Working sscanf for Python (preferrably py3k)?

Tags: python, printf, scanf

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2175080/309483), but I am having problems with the [top solution](https://hkn.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dyoo/python/scanf/). 
For example:

```
>>> scanf.sscanf("\"test\"","\"%s\"")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "scanf.py", line 393, in sscanf
    return bscanf(CharacterBufferFromIterable(inputString), formatString)
  File "scanf.py", line 414, in bscanf
    return parser(buffer)
  File "scanf.py", line 577, in __call__
    raise IncompleteCaptureError(e, tuple(results))
scanf.IncompleteCaptureError: (FormatError('" != ',), ('test"',))
>>>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this not supposed to work?

Comment: Seems like a bug in their library...Do you need to get the quotes?

Comment: The scanf module appears to assume the quote is part of the string.  It doesn't seem to handle %s followed by letters very well (that's a more complex parser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrapped [the parse module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse):

```python
from parse import parse
parse("\"%s\"".replace("%s","{}"), "\"test\"").fixed
```