# Making a decryption program in python

Tags: python, encryption

So a little while ago I asked for some help with an encryption program,
And you guys were amazing and came up with the solution.
So I come to you again in search of help for the equivalent decryption program.
The code I have got so far is like this:

```
whinger = 0
bewds = raw_input ('Please enter the encrypted message: ')
bewds = bewds.replace(' ', ', ')
warble = [bewds]
print warble
wetler = len(warble)
warble.reverse();
while whinger < wetler:
    print chr(warble[whinger]),
    whinger += 1
```

But when I input
`101 103 97 115 115 101 109`
it comes up with the error that the input is not an integer.
What I need is when I enter the numbers it turns them into a list of integers.
But I don't want to have to input all the numbers separately.

Thanks in advance for your help :P

Answer (score 2):

To convert input string into a list of integers:

```
numbers = [int(s) for s in "101 103 97 115 115 101 109".split()]
```

Comment: He is also adding `','`. So he might need to do a `split(', ')` or just stop adding commas.

Comment: @aychedee: `split(", ")` won't work if there is no space after comma and it won't split integers separated by whitespace. [@martineau's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14704368/4279) with `replace(",", " ").split()` could be used to support both spaces and commas. Though I'd limit valid input only to spaces for simplicity.

Comment: Yeah, but he was explicitly replacing spaces with `, `. (comma, space) So :-P

Answer (score 1):

Here's almost the simplest way I can think of to do it:

```
s = '101 103 97 115 115 101 109'
numbers = []
for number_str in s.replace(',', ' ').split():
    numbers.append(int(number_str))
```

It will allow the numbers to be separated with commas and/or one or more space characters. If you only want to allow spaces, leave the "`.replace(',', ' ')`" out.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that raw_input returns a string to you. So you have two options.

1, Use regular expression library re. E.G.:

```
import re
bewds = raw_input ('Please enter the encrypted message: ')
some_list = []
for find in re.finditer("\d+", bewds):
    some_list.append(find.group(0))
```

2, Or you can use split method as described in the most voted answer to this question: [sscanf in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175080/sscanf-in-python)

Comment: Sure, that's why I have mentioned it :-) But asking guy is obviously new in python so a little more options, how to do that, won't do any harm :-)

Comment: IMHO, someone new should be shown the simplest way(s) to do it first.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `map`

```
numbers = map(int, '101 103 97 115 115 101 109'.split())
```

This returns a list in Python 2, but a `map` object in Python 3, which you might want to convert into a list.

```
numbers = list(map(int, '101 103 97 115 115 101 109'.split()))
```

This does exactly the same as [J. F. Sebastian's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14703895/1907098)