# How do I read the next integer ignoring whitespace in Python?

Tags: python, input, python-3.x

How do I read the next integer ignoring whitespace in Python 3?  Is there a way to make a generator that returns integers from a stream of whitespace-separated integers?

The best I have is this:

```
def ints():
    while True:
        yield from (int(x) for x in input().split())
```

Comment: Do you want to keep reading from command line for a potentially infinite amount of time?

Comment: You don't want to use input(), that will `eval` your code. Use raw_input instead. http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905866/python-stream-extraction

Comment: @murphh: sorry, edited the question.

Comment: @JonClements: OP is using Python3, in which `input` [works differently](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#input)

Comment: Oh, indeed! I didn't know that difference. Thanks!

Comment: Neil, tell us why you think your example is insufficient. What is making you search for another solution?

Comment: @Robᵩ: I would like to actually have something like java's scanner where I can "get next int" or "get next float"

Answer (score 3):

Complete ignoring white space and reading from a file (treating an integer purely as consecutive digits):

```
import mmap
import re

with open('somefile', 'rb') as fin:
    mf = mmap.mmap(fin.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    for digits in re.finditer('(\d+)', mf):
        print(digits.group(1))
```

Or, if you've already got everything in a string, then adapt the `finditer` appropriately, maybe something like:

```
yield from (match.group(1) for match in re.finditer('\d+', some_string))
```

Comment: I deleted my attempt because I prefer this method. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading from stdin, you can do this:

```
import sys

def ints():
    for line in sys.stdin:
        rtr=[int(d) for d in line.split() if d.isdigit()] 
        if rtr:
            for n in rtr:
                yield n

print(list(ints()))
```

Or, if your Py 3.3+ supports generator delegation:

```
import sys

def ints():
    for line in sys.stdin:
         yield from (int(d) for d in line.split() if d.isdigit())
```

You can also use the very slick [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) which has the advantage of supporting both a file name (and the file by that name will then be opened and read) or input from the redirected stdin:

```
import fileinput

def ints():
    for line in fileinput.input():
        yield from (int(d) for d in line.split() if d.isdigit())
```

(If you test fileinput directly or manually, know that you need to end the input with two <kbd>Ctl</kbd>D's -- not just one....)

Comment: I'd probably go for `iter(input, '')` here instead of the `while True` and `sys.stdin.readline()`

Comment: @JonClements: I think just using `for line in sys.stdin:` instead of `While True` is even better. Thanks!

Comment: I would replace []-s to ()-s in the generator expressions.