# python function to get the number of values read using input() function

Tags: python

In C language, the `scanf()` function will return the number of data read into the variables. Is it possible to get the number of variables read using `input()` function in python? for eg.

```
v = scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
```

returns the number of integer variable read using `scanf()` function. If the three variable values are not integers it will return the value less than three.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sscanf in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175080/sscanf-in-python)

Comment: And perhaps of interest: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/502213/

Comment: how would `scanf` work with `"%d%d%d"` without whitespace to delimit the three ints?  Do you want `"%d %d %d"`?

Comment: @RyanHaining, "%d" skips spaces itself. It works absolutely fine

Answer (score 2):

You may need

```
len(raw_input().split())
```

It doesn't check arguments for being integers through. You may use

```
numbers = map(int, raw_input().split())
```

to cast input to integers. You will get an exception (`ValueError`) in case of wrong format

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input()` reads exactly 1 line. If you want to know what was in the line, you can do the usual things: call `len`, `split` it, try to convert it into an `int`, etc.

`input()` should not be used; it's equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`, and malformed or malicious input can do nasty things to your program if you use it. If you really want to use `input()`, you can inspect the value it returns the usual ways.

Comment: or OP is using python3