# Python alternative to fscanf C code

Tags: python, c, python-2.7

I have some C code that works well:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    struct emp
    {
        char name[40];
        int age;
        float bs;
    };
    struct emp e;
    fp=fopen("EMPLOYEE.DAT","r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        puts("Cannot open file";
        exit(1);
    }
    while(fscanf(f,"%s %d %f",&e.name,&e.age,&e.bs)!=EOF)
        printf("%s %d %f\n",e.name,e.age,e.bs);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

data inside `EMPLOYEE.DAT`:

```
Sunil 34 1250.50
Sameer 21 1300.50
rahul 34 1400.50
```

I'm having trouble translating this code to Python:

```
while(fscanf(f,"%s %d %f",&e.name,&e.age,&e.bs)!=EOF)
    printf("%s %d %f\n",e.name,e.age,e.bs);
```

Is there any way to implement that in Python? Furthermore, what are Pythonic alternatives of `exit()` & `EOF`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sscanf in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175080/sscanf-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like:

```
with open("EMPLOYEE.DAT") as f: # open the file for reading
    for line in f: # iterate over each line
        name, age, bs = line.split() # split it by whitespace
        age = int(age) # convert age from string to int
        bs = float(bs) # convert bs from string to float
        print(name, age, bs)
```

If you want to store the data in a structure, you can use the builtin `dict` type (hash map)

```
person = {'name': name, 'age': age, 'bs': bs}
person['name'] # access data
```

Or you could define your own class:

```
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age, bs):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.bs = bs

e = Employee(name, age, bs) # create an instance
e.name # access data
```

**EDIT**

Here's a version that handles the error if the file does not exist. And returns an `exit` code.

```
import sys
try:
    with open("EMPLOYEE.DAT") as f:
        for line in f:
            name, age, bs = line.split()
            age = int(age)
            bs = float(bs)
            print(name, age, bs)
except IOError:
    print("Cannot open file")
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: `for line in f:` would suffice to avoid reading the file all at once using `f.readlines`. It matches the behavior more closely anyway.