# Parse string to appropriate variables

Tags: python

```
[[{"date":"January 2004"},true,false,100,null,null,true],[{"date":"February 2004"},false,false,99,null,null,true]]
```

I have a long string of data that came from a javascript file, like the above. Is there a short cut or library that would parse this into the appropriate data types?

As you can see, it's a list of lists that contain dictionaries, Boolean values, integers and null values.

I mean, I could do this by hand but I don't think I could do it very quickly or efficiently. There must be a better method.

Comment: Are there really no closing `}` brackets for those `{` brackets?

Comment: No, my mistake. I was trying to simplify the full version. I corrected it above.

Comment: Isn't this just [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)? Not sure why it has `True`/`False` instead of `true`/`false` though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's *pretty* close to valid JSON. The only invalid thing is that `False` should be `false` and `True` should be `true`.  That could be a transcription error (...yep)

---

Use `json`:

```
import json

x = '[[{"date":"January 2004"},true,false,100,null,null,true],[{"date":"February 2004"},false,false,99,null,null,true]]'

json.loads(x)
Out[20]: 
[[{'date': 'January 2004'}, True, False, 100, None, None, True],
 [{'date': 'February 2004'}, False, False, 99, None, None, True]]
```

Comment: macdonjo says he's getting the output from JavaScript, so I wonder if he capitalized the Boolean values when he was posting the data...

Comment: Yes, you guys got me again, I capitalized them just because I was working in Python and it didn't cross my mind that it would make a difference. Yep, they're lowercase! :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at PyParsing.

http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/

You could also take a look at the Python "scanf" library.

[sscanf in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175080/sscanf-in-python)

If you needed to solve this problem just using Python built-ins, I would recommend using a regular expression with capture groups.

EDIT:  Hmm, I took another look at this.  You did say it was from JavaScript... this looks to me like a legal JSON array.  I tried using the `json` module (specifically, the method function `json.loads()`) but I couldn't get it to parse.

But!  Python syntax is close to JavaScript syntax.  Replace a few things and `eval()` can parse this, or `ast.literal_eval()`.  We need to replace `true` with `True`, `false` with `False`, and `null` with `None` before `ast.literal_eval()` will accept it.

```
import ast
s = '[[{"date":"January 2004"},True,False,100,null,null,true],[{"date":"February 2004"},False,False,99,null,null,true]]'
s1 = s.replace("true","True").replace("false","False").replace("null","None")
x = ast.literal_eval(s1)
print(x)
```

The above will print:

```
[[{'date': 'January 2004'}, True, False, 100, None, None, True], [{'date': 'February 2004'}, False, False, 99, None, None, True]]
```

Originally I showed defining variables (like `true = True`) and using `eval()` to parse this, but of course `eval()` is a potential security hole; so if you need to parse text that might come from a web page or any other untrusted source, it's worth the small amount of effort to import `ast` and use `ast.literal_eval()` instead.

EDIT: Okay, the `json` module can parse this; the problem was the use of `True` instead of `true` and `False` instead of `false`.  Just use the `str.replace()` method function to fix those, and then `json.loads()` can parse this.

I was just about to post a code fragment with the `.replace()` method calls, when the question got updated again, and the capitalized `True` and `False` became ordinary legal JSON ones.

So my final answer:

```
s = '[[{"date":"January 2004"},true,false,100,null,null,true],[{"date":"February 2004"},false,false,99,null,null,true]]'

import json

x = json.loads(s)
print(x)
```

prints:

```
[[{u'date': u'January 2004'}, True, False, 100, None, None, True], [{u'date': u'February 2004'}, False, False, 99, None, None, True]]
```

Comment: You didn't enter the eval argument as a string. Remember, it's a string.

Comment: @macdonjo Thanks for pointing that out.  When I tested it, it worked, but when I typed it in here I failed to put the string quotes.  Usually I copy/paste from my Python session so I'm putting the correct tested code, but I must not have done that this time; I wonder why not.

Comment: As for the source of the data, it's from a very popular website and it's not user entered. It's just a big database. So I guess this should be safe?

Comment: It's probably safe, but if you were going to do the "eval" trick I would suggest using `ast.literal_eval()` anyway.  I'll modify my example to use that.  But you might as well use `json.loads()` since it really is legal JSON.

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing