# Reversing str.format() - getting arguments by placeholder

Tags: python-2.7, text-extraction, string.format

What is the most elegant way to reverse the process of Python's str.format on replacing arguments by position?

For example for the following

```
textpattern = 'Please move {0} to {1}'
mystring = 'Please move a to b'
```

a `deformat` function :

```
mystring.deformat(textpattern)
```

will return the list `['a', 'b']`. The variable `textpattern` is being entered by the user and then dynamically fetched from the DB.

The closest thing I found is [a question about scnaf in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175080/sscanf-in-python) but that's slightly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the package [`parse`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse) which is described as: parse() is the opposite of format().