# (Python3) Is there something similar to scanf in Python?

Tags: python, input

I know there's `input()` which stores the entire input into a variable and I can just use regex from it, but what I want is a quick function that look for a *specific pattern* in the input, match it and store it into a variable.

For example, in C to store just the day,month and year from an input:

```
printf("Type your birthday (dd/mm/yyyy):\n")
scanf("%d/%d/%d", &d,&m,&y)    // <---
```

Is there something equivalent in Python?

Comment: Umm. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#simulating-scanf

Comment: I see, so it doesn't exist... Thanks.

Comment: Yup. [Also in the FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html?highlight=scanf#is-there-a-scanf-or-sscanf-equivalent)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sscanf in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175080/sscanf-in-python)