# scanf() production problems in Python

Tags: python, c, input

I wanted to try writing functions of a language to a different one. I opt for C to Python, and here is what I've done so far.

Code:

```
def printf(text, *args):
    print(text % args, end = '')

def scanf(text, *args):
    args = input(text % args)
    return args

name = None
scanf("What's your name? %s", name)
printf("Hello, %s.\n", name)
```

Result:

```
What's your name? NoneBoy
Hello, Boy.
```

I have 3 problems regarding this question:

1. `scanf` doesn't actually print out the variable to be inputted.
2. I have to implement a variable with no value, but unlike C, where you could just write `int result;`, you must write it as `result = None` and my function would print `None` as well.
3. It never returned any value.

Are there any solutions I can use to fix these?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175080/sscanf-in-python

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev yes it's right. Thanks a lot of sharing this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use static variables for updating any value inside the function.

```
class Example:
    name = "None"

def printf(text, args):
    print(text % args, end = '')

def scanf(text, args):
    Example.name = input(text)

scanf("What's your name? ", name)
printf("Hello, %s.\n", Example.name)
```

There are other pre-build functions to use.
This is the example of the user-defined functions.
If you want to use a pre-defined function. Please let me know.